# How to simplify function to $\log (1-\theta)+\frac{\theta}{2-\theta}$?

Tags: functions, logarithms, entropy, copula

\begin{align}
f(\theta)& = \log \frac{1}{1-\theta}-\frac{\theta}{2-\theta}+\frac{\theta^{2}}{(2-\theta)^{2}} \\
& = \log (1-\theta)+\frac{\theta}{2-\theta}
\end{align}
How are the two equations above equal to each other, i.e. reduce the first into the second?

How can one term be outside of the logarithm on the second line, whereas all 3 terms fall inside the logarithm on the first line? Actually, I'm not even sure if all the terms in the first line are supposed to all fall inside the logarithm, no brackets were given, so it could be either or

Source of first equation:

- Formula 22 in [Mercier 2005](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.212.8739&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Source of second equation:

- Formula 4.4 in [Kumar 2011](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/872e/57fd2fab8327a46209373ccd9b8850264463.pdf)

If they don't equal each other like how the second author claims, which author made a mistake?

#### Edit

I found yet another equality presented by the same second author. This time,

- Formula 3.41 of [Kumar 2014](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Pranesh_Kumar/publication/266999229_Some_properties_of_the_Marshall-Olkin_and_generalized_Cuadras-Auge_families_of_copulas/links/560b2d2d08ae576ce6410778/Some-properties-of-the-Marshall-Olkin-and-generalized-Cuadras-Auge-families-of-copulas.pdf):

$$
f(\theta) = \log (1-\theta)+\frac{2 \theta(1-\theta)}{(2-\theta)^{2}}
$$

Comment: This reads as $\log \left( \frac{1}{1 - \theta} \right)$ where the brackets enclose $\frac{1}{1 - \theta}$. On the first line there are three terms, and on the second line, there are two terms.

Comment: yes, i said that without giving  the counts of 2 and 3. we are seeing the same thing. whichever one is right for the first line, as I discuss in the second paragraph, I still don't see how they reduce for either

Answer (score 3):

The first line is not equal to the second line:

$$f(\theta) = \log \left( \frac{1}{1-\theta} \right)-\frac{\theta}{2-\theta}+\frac{\theta^{2}}{(2-\theta)^{2}}$$
$$= \log( (1 - \theta)^{-1}) - \frac{\theta (2 - \theta)}{(2 - \theta)^2} + \frac{\theta^{2}}{(2-\theta)^{2}}$$
$$= -\log(1 - \theta) + \frac{-(2\theta - \theta^2) + \theta^2}{(2 - \theta)^2}$$
$$= -\log(1 - \theta) + \frac{2 \theta^2 - 2 \theta}{(2 - \theta)^2}$$
$$= -\log(1 - \theta) + \frac{(2\theta)(\theta - 1)}{(2 - \theta)^2}$$

Comment: what if you start from $$f(\theta) = \log \left( \frac{1}{1-\theta} -\frac{\theta}{2-\theta}+\frac{\theta^{2}}{(2-\theta)^{2}}\right)$$

Comment: You can try graphing it on Desmos / GeoGebra. None of the options work.

Comment: I added the sources of the two equations

Comment: This might be useful: [What should/can I do on finding an error in a published article?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3445) on Academia SE.

Comment: see edit showing a third article whose formula is most similar to your result, but still not quite the same

Comment: That's very strange. I assume you are familiar with the papers, so you should definitely contact the authors.